# How can object orientation help create efficient code?

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a series of python functions, and I am trying to find the most pythonic way to structure my code. These functions generally work as follows:

```
def Function1():
    a = 1
    return a

def Function2():
    b = Function1()
    return b+1

def Function3():
    c = Function2()
    return c+1

def Function4():
    d = Function3()
    return d+1

def Function5():
    e = Function3()
    return e+2

i = Function4()
j = Function5()
```

You can see that these functions are daisy-chained, and that the executable pattern forks at function 3, such that functions 4 and 5 derive from 3. By my understanding, the preceding code executes functions 1, 2, 3, and 4, and then executes functions 1, 2, 3, and 5--for a total of 8 executions.

Obviously this is quite labor-intensive and confusing as the code scales up. It is desirable to execute functions 1, 2, 3, store function 3 in memory, and use function 3 to execute functions 4 and 5--for a total of 5 executions. Without object orientation, my two options are either A) continue executing inefficient code or B) define function 3 globally and use that global definition to execute functions 4 and 5 (confusing, and not desirable).

I believe that classes and object orientation may help my code become more efficient. This is my best approach so far, which seems to produce the same result:

```
class A: 

    def Function1():
        a = 1
        return a
    
    def Function2():
        b = A.Function1()
        return b + 1
    
    def Function3():
        c = A.Function2()
        return c + 1
    

class B: 

    x = A.Function3()    

    def Function4():
        d = B.x
        return d+1
    
    def Function5():
        e = B.x
        return e+2
        

i = B.Function4()
j = B.Function5()
```

I believe that the preceding code executes functions 1, 2, and 3, stores function 3 in memory. It then defines function 3 as an object (x) and uses that object to execute functions 4 and 5--for a total of 5 executions, as desired. Is this correct? In other words, is this considered efficient code?

Second question: is this truly the most pythonic way to handle this code? My goal is clarity and efficiency.

Comment: OOP does not magically improve your code just because you're suddenly using classes; it improves your code because it allows you to model real-life objects (Account, Screen, Book, Car), which *have certain aspects* (attributes) and *can do certain things* (methods). This, in turn, makes your code easier to read, understand, reason about, and work with. Both your examples are similarly complex to me, because I don't know what you're trying to model or achieve.

Comment: Your OO version isn't at all equivalent to the original version. You only call `A.Function3()` once, when class `B` is defined, instead of every time `B.Function4()` is called.

Comment: @jfaccioni should make an answer of his comment, that is spot on! Also mention that these objects contains only class methods, there is no self reference, to be able to model those objects you mentioned.

Comment: @Barmar this directly addresses one of my questions, thank you. Assuming that each function takes 1-second to execute, am I correct in thinking that the first block of code would take 8 seconds, whereas the second block would only take 5 seconds to execute?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It will take 3 seconds to define class A, then 1 second for each B.function4 and B.function5

Comment: But you can accomplish the same thing with functions by saving the result of `Function3()` in a variable that `Function4()` and `Function5()` access.